# git PR from one branch to base shows no diff where I expected a diff?

Tags: git, github, branch, pull-request

1. I first created a branch, let's call it `base`.
2. I pushed that branch to the remote.
3. I then realized that `base` was too big, and wanted to extract some stuff into its own branch/PR.
4. I created `small` off `base`.
5. Pushed `small` to remote
6. I then basically removed a whole directory from `base`.
7. Pushed the new `base`
8. Went to create a new PR from `small` to `base` on github

To my surprise, github says there's no difference, that `small` contains all commits in `base`. However, if I run `(small) git diff base` my local git shows the expected difference.

Why does github say otherwise?
I then tried to change `small` with a small nit (just comments), and now github even says it can't merge it and shows a conflict - but only about the nit diff, not the expected whole directory.

A bit mysterious to me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you created `small` off of `base`, both of these branches point to the same commit.  When you removed the directory on `base` this was a new commit that exists only on that branch.  So `base` now has this commit and `small` does not.
When Github is generating the diff, it is going to only look at the commits that are on the branch that it will be merging from (in this case `small`) that don't exist in the branch it is merging into.  There aren't any.  So the diff is empty.

If you want to create smaller MR's, create a new branch off of what you were going to merge `base` into and use `git checkout base -- <directory>` (or small) to get the files from the branch.  Commit this and create your PR's with these other branches.

Comment: Looks like you understood the core here! Thanks first of all. In fact, I think I have had similar issues in the past. So I need to learn to apply the process you are proposing. However, now that I already have `base` - would I first have to delete `base` in order to run `git checkout base -- <directory> ` ?

Comment: I just realized another option is to just move the directory to `/tmp`, reset hard `small` to `base`, and then copy the dir back into `base`...

Comment: You need to keep base in order to run `git checkout base`, if the branch doesn't exist, you can't check it out.  You need to get commits with your changes into `small`